# Load environment variables using include_vars in Ansible

Tags: ansible

There is a environment variable file which has key value pairs. I want to read its content using `include_vars` but `include_vars` only accepts `json` or `yaml`

**.env.dev**

```
FOO=bar
TEST=1
```

**playbook**

```
   tasks:
   - include_vars:
       file: "../vars/staging/core/.env.dev"
       name: "envs_dev"
```

This throws an error like `Syntax Error while loading YAML.` which makes sense cause the file is not a yaml.

What is the best practice to load this env var file content to a variable in ansible?

Comment: You can use `{{ lookup('ini', 'FOO file=.env.dev') }}` since this confirms to INI (key=value) syntax. Alternatively, source the file before running the playbook(s) and use `lookup('env', 'FOO')`.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files

```
 vars_files:
    - ../vars/staging/core/.env.dev
```

And the .env.dev

```
FOO: bar
TEST: 1
```